# Populating ListView inside Fragment class extending ListFragment

Tags: android, mobile

I have a fragment class extending ListFragment and I'm having trouble populating the list.

I run an asynctask to retreive and parse data from a webservice which is all working ok but now I'm stuck on where I should set the list adapter to populate my list.

I am currently executing my asynctask in the onCreate() method and trying to populate the list in onActivity created which gives a NullPointerException. If i remove the setListAdapter everything runs fine.

According to the android developer docs, a fragment extending ListFragment returns a ListView from onCreateView() by default so I should have access to it.

Where is the correct place to set my list adapter to populate the list?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to set the list adapter in the `onPostExecute()` in the `AsyncTask`. You can pass a reference to the `ListFragment` into the constructor for `AsyncTask` and call `setListAdapter()` on that reference.

Comment: Thankyou @kmdupr33 works great! Do you know how I can store the adapter in onSavedInstanceState as I only run this asynctask the first time the fragment is loaded? Thankyou

Comment: I actually don't know how to do this. Sorry. I'm pretty new to android dev too. ;)